# PHP file with multiple email sending forms

Tags: php, html

I have a page with 2 order forms - one for private ant the other for business. I need that when a person submits my form he would see a message on a page or an alert without redirecting to any other php files - everything should take place in the same file. My php file now looks something like this(it's a demo) and it doesn't work I just know that there are no php syntax errors(the problem should be with my code logic):

```
<?php
 header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');

if ($_POST['private-submit'] == 1) {
if(isset($_POST['private'])) {

/// Php mail code content


@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
  $feedback = 'You have been registered!';}
}



if ($_POST['business-submit'] == 2) {
if(isset($_POST['business'])) {

      /// Php mail code content



@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
  $feedback = 'You have been registered!';}

}
?>

    <form id="a" name="private" method="post" action="?">

       <ul> 
       <li> <input type="text" name="private" placeholder="private*" required></li>

        <button  name="private-submit" type="submit" class="submit" value="1">Order</button>
        </li>
      <p id="feedback"><?php echo $feedback; ?></p>  

      </ul>
    </form>

 <form id="b" name="business" method="post" action="?">


       <ul> 
       <li> <input type="text" name="business" placeholder="business" required></li>     

        <button  name="business-submit" type="submit"  value="2">Order</button>
        </li>
      <p id="feedback"><?php echo $feedback; ?></p>

      </ul>
    </form>
```